# Learn Python The Hard Way, Ex21 Q3

Tags: python-2.7

I tried to write a code using the advise of Zed Shaw below:

What do you mean by "write out a formula"?
Try 24 + 34 / 100 - 1023 as a start. Convert that to use the functions.

Here is my code:

```
def add(a, b):
    print "Adding %s + %s" % (a, b)
    return a + b

def divide(a, b):
    print "Dividing %r / %r" % (a, b)
    return a / b

def subtract(a, b):
    print "Subtracting %s - %s" % (a, b)
    return a - b

cats = (24)
dogs = subtract(100, 1023)
monsters = divide(34.0, 100)

print "cats: %r, dogs: %r, monsters: %r" % (cats, dogs, monsters)

Result = subtract(dogs, add(cats, divide(monsters,1)))

print "That becomes:", Result, "Can you do it by hand?"
```

The problem is that when I calculate 24 + 34 / 100 - 1023 by hand I get the total of -998.6. But my above code gives me - 947.34. I am wondering where is my mistake. How should the correct code for this 24 + 34 / 100 - 1023 look like?

Or I have the same code slightly modified, and still have a different result: -981,34:

```
def add(a, b):
    print "Adding %s + %s" % (a, b)
    return a + b

def divide(a, b):
    print "Dividing %r / %r" % (a, b)
    return a / b

def subtract(a, b):
    print "Subtracting %s - %s" % (a, b)
    return a - b

cats = add(24, 34)
dogs = subtract(100, 1023)
monsters = divide(34.0, 100)

print "cats: %r, dogs: %r, monsters: %r" % (cats, dogs, monsters)

Result = subtract(dogs, add(cats, divide(monsters,100)))

print "That becomes:", Result, "Can you do it by hand?"
```

Thanks for your help and pieces of advise.

Answer (score 0):

With a help of a colleague, I have found a solution to the above problem. I had to create values like x, y, z and w for example. Here is the code that makes this work:

```
def add(a, b):
    print "Adding %s + %s" % (a, b)
    return a + b

def divide(a, b):
    print "Dividing %r / %r" % (a, b)
    return a / b

def subtract(a, b):
    print "Subtracting %s - %s" % (a, b)
    return a - b

x = 34.0
y = 100
z = 24
w = 1023
monsters = divide(x, y)
cats = add(z, monsters)
dogs = subtract(cats, w)

print "cats: %r, dogs: %r, monsters: %r" % (cats, dogs, monsters)

#Result = add(cats, divide(monsters, subtract(dogs, 1023)))
#Result = add(cats, subtract(dogs, divide(monsters, 100)))
Result = dogs
#Result = divide(monsters, add(cats, subtract(dogs, 1023)))

print "That becomes:", Result, "Can you do it by hand?"

#24 + 34 / 100 - 1023

#float(raw_input())
```

But this code does not follow the logic of the EX21. If anyone has a better solution, please share it here.

Answer (score 0):

And here is another solution, although the number originally has to be -998.66. Instead the below code results in 998.66. So definitely there is still something hiding from me :)

```
def add(a, b):
    print "Adding %s + %s" % (a, b)
    return a + b

def divide(a, b):
    print "Dividing %r / %r" % (a, b)
    return a / b

def subtract(a, b):
    print "Subtracting %s - %s" % (a, b)
    return a - b

monsters = (34.0)
cats = (24)
dogs = (1023)

print "cats: %r, dogs: %r, monsters: %r" % (cats, dogs, monsters)

#Result = add(cats, divide(monsters, subtract(dogs, 1023)))
#Result = add(cats, subtract(dogs, divide(monsters, 100)))
#Result = dogs
#Result = divide(monsters, 100), add(cats, subtract(dogs))))
Result = subtract(dogs, add(cats, divide(monsters, 100)))
#Result = add(cats, divide(monsters, 100), subtract(dogs)))
#Result = subtract(dogs, divide(monsters, 100), add(cats)))

print "That becomes:", Result, "Can you do it by hand?"

#24 + 34 / 100 - 1023

#float(raw_input())
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Function Can Return Someting 
def add(a, b):
    print (f"ADDING %d + %d" % (a, b))
    return a + b
def subtract(a, b):
    print (f"SUBTRACTING %d - %d" % (a, b))
    return a - b
def multiply(a, b):
    print (f"MULTIPLYING %d * %d" % (a, b)) 
    return a * b
def divide(a, b):
    print (f"DIVIDING %d / %d" % (a, b)) 
    return a / b
print ("Let's do some math with just functions!")

a = 24.0
b = 34.0
c = 100.0
d = 1023.0

print (f"a: %d, b: %d, c: %d, d: %d" % (a, b, c, d))

# A puzzle for the extra credit, type it in anyway.
print ("Here is a puzzle.")
what = subtract(add(a,divide(b,c)),d)
# Or simply do : what = subtract(add(24,divide(34,100)),1023)
print ("That becomes: ", what, "Can you do it by hand?")
```